# Implementing canActivate in Angular 2

Tags: angular, angular2-routing

I am new to Angular 2 and I am trying to implement role 
based authentication with the following code as mentioned below.Where can I pass or check the particular user has access to that role.What am I doing wrong here?
Please Suggest

**app.module.ts**

```
const appRoutes: Routes = [
  { path: '', component: LoginComponent },
  { path: 'main', component: MainComponent }
];

const appChildRoutes: Routes = [
  {
    path: 'main', component: MainComponent,
    canActivateChild: [RoleGuard],
    children: [
      {
        path: 'charts', component: ChartsComponent, canActivateChild: [RoleGuard],
        data: { roles: ['user', 'admin'] }
      },
      { path: 'overview', component: OverviewComponent, canActivateChild: [RoleGuard],
        data: { roles: ['user', 'admin'] } },
      { path: 'demand', component: DemandComponent, canActivateChild: [RoleGuard],
        data: { roles: ['user', 'admin'] } },
      { path: 'analysis', component: AnalysisComponent, canActivateChild: [RoleGuard],
        data: { roles: ['user', 'admin'] } },
      { path: 'approval', component: ApprovalComponent, canActivateChild: [RoleGuard],
        data: { roles: ['user', 'admin'] } },
      { path: 'demand/:demand', component: DemandComponent, canActivateChild: [RoleGuard],
        data: { roles: ['user', 'admin'] } }
    ]
  }
]
```

**roleguard.ts**

```
export class RoleGuard implements CanActivate,CanActivateChild{


    canActivate(route: ActivatedRouteSnapshot,
    state: RouterStateSnapshot): boolean {
    console.log("*******************Can Activate Called*************************");

    let roles = route.data["roles"] as Array<string>;
    console.log("state"+state);
    return (roles == null || roles.indexOf("the-logged-user-role") != -1);
}

      canActivateChild(route: ActivatedRouteSnapshot,
    state: RouterStateSnapshot): boolean {
        console.log("********************Can Activate Child Called**********************");

    let roles = route.data["roles"] as Array<string>;
    console.log("state"+state);
    return (roles == null || roles.indexOf("the-logged-user-role") != -1);
}


}
```

Comment: I guess `roles` is still `null` when this code that checks `roles.indexOf()` is executed. You probably need to subscribe to observables. Hard to give concrete information without seeing what code loads `roles`.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I have created a [Plunker](https://plnkr.co/edit/nILcVfSsP8uOkdP4k34U?p=preview) with router role permissions check.

1. I would change:

   ```
   const appRoutes: Routes = [
    { path: '', component: LoginComponent },
     { path: 'main', component: MainComponent }
    ];

    const appChildRoutes: Routes = [
    {
   path: 'main', component: MainComponent,
   canActivateChild: [RoleGuard],
   children: [
     {
       path: 'charts', component: ChartsComponent, canActivateChild: [RoleGuard],
       data: { roles: ['user', 'admin'] }
     },
     { path: 'overview', component: OverviewComponent, canActivateChild: [RoleGuard],
       data: { roles: ['user', 'admin'] } },
     { path: 'demand', component: DemandComponent, canActivateChild: [RoleGuard],
       data: { roles: ['user', 'admin'] } },
     { path: 'analysis', component: AnalysisComponent, canActivateChild: [RoleGuard],
       data: { roles: ['user', 'admin'] } },
     { path: 'approval', component: ApprovalComponent, canActivateChild: [RoleGuard],
       data: { roles: ['user', 'admin'] } },
     { path: 'demand/:demand', component: DemandComponent, canActivateChild: [RoleGuard],
       data: { roles: ['user', 'admin'] } }
       ]
       }
     ]
   ```

   to

   ```
   path: 'main', component: MainComponent, canActivate: [RoleGuard], 
   data: { roles: ['user', 'admin'] } },
     children: [
     {
       path: 'charts', component: ChartsComponent,  
     },
     { path: 'overview', component: OverviewComponent, 
        },
     { path: 'demand', component: DemandComponent, 
        },
     { path: 'analysis', component: AnalysisComponent, 
        },
     { path: 'approval', component: ApprovalComponent, 
        },
     { path: 'demand/:demand', component: DemandComponent, 
        } }
       ]
       }
     ]
   ```

   and remove all CanActivateChild in child routes.
2. You can use [ngx-permissions](https://github.com/AlexKhymenko/ngx-permissions). Or any other similar library.